# React Date Picker color effect on hover and set date range

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently using React to build a Date Picker Component, where you can set a date range. 
As inspiratoin and model I used the [airbnb react-dates package](https://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-calendar-props--single-month). 
Now, I managed to build the funcitonality of the date picker, but I don't really know how to achieve the color change of all dates in between the start and end date. 
Because in the airbnb version as soon as you set a start date, it automatically sets all the days between the start date and the mouse cursor in another color. This effect is also present, when both a start date and an end date are set (see attachment for reference).

[image: Date Picker Hover effect]

Here is my code, I am also happy for every imporvement suggestion :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//component
function Test() {
  const currentDate = new Date();

  //state for the datepicker month and year heading
  let [datePicker, setDatePicker] = useState({
    currentMonth: currentDate.getMonth(),
    currentYear: currentDate.getFullYear(),
  });

  //state that stores start and end date and keeps track which date is currently selected to be overridden
  let [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    selectStartDate: true,
    selectEndDate: false,
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  });

  //useEffect that colors the current start and end date in a different color
  useEffect(() => {
    let startClass = document.querySelector('.start-date');
    let endClass = document.querySelector('.end-date');

    if (startClass) startClass.classList.remove('start-date');
    if (endClass) endClass.classList.remove('end-date');

    if (dateRange.startDate) {
      let startDateAttribute = getDateFormatted(dateRange.startDate);
      let start = document.querySelectorAll(`[day="${startDateAttribute}"]`)[0];
      if (start) start.classList.add('start-date');
    }
    if (dateRange.endDate) {
      let endDateAttribute = getDateFormatted(dateRange.endDate);
      let end = document.querySelectorAll(`[day="${endDateAttribute}"]`)[0];
      if (end) end.classList.add('end-date');
    }
  }, [dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate, datePicker.currentMonth, datePicker.currentYear]);

  //initializes the grid and gets the days of the current month and year
  const monthGrid = [];
  getMonthGrid(datePicker.currentYear, datePicker.currentMonth, monthGrid);

  //takes the monthgrid and maps it to day elements that are then displayed on the page
  const days = monthGrid.map((element, id) => {
    if (element === null) {
      return <div className='day empty-day' key={id}></div>;
    }
    let date = new Date(datePicker.currentYear, datePicker.currentMonth, element);
    date = getDateFormatted(date);
    return (
      <div className='day' key={date} day={date} onClick={(e) => onClickDateRange(e)}>
        {element}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100vh',
      }}
    >
      <div className='date-picker'>
        <div className='input-container'>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='start-date'
            className='date-picker__input'
            placeholder='Start Date'
            value={dateRange.startDate ? getDateFormatted(dateRange.startDate) : ''}
            onClick={onInputStartClick}
          />
          <input
            type='text'
            name='end-date'
            className='date-picker__input'
            placeholder='End Date'
            value={dateRange.endDate ? getDateFormatted(dateRange.endDate) : ''}
            onClick={onInputEndClick}
          />
        </div>

        <div className='year-container'>
          <button className='prev-month' onClick={prevMonth}>
            Prev
          </button>
          <h2>{`${getMonthTitle(datePicker.currentMonth)} ${datePicker.currentYear}`}</h2>
          <button className='next-month' onClick={nextMonth}>
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className='week-container'>
          <div>Mo</div>
          <div>Tu</div>
          <div>We</div>
          <div>Th</div>
          <div>Fr</div>
          <div>Sa</div>
          <div>So</div>
        </div>
        <div className='days'>{days}</div>
        <button onClick={getNumberOfDays}>Submit</button>
        <button onClick={clearDateRange}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  //MAIN FUNCTIONS
  //gets the days of the current month and year
  function getMonthGrid(year, month, monthGrid) {
    const firstDayType = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
    const lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
    let lastDayType = lastDay.getDay();
    const numberOfDays = lastDay.getDate();

    if (firstDayType === 0) {
      for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        monthGrid.push(null);
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 1; i < firstDayType; i++) {
        monthGrid.push(null);
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
      monthGrid.push(i + 1);
    }

    if (lastDayType !== 0) {
      for (lastDayType; lastDayType < 7; lastDayType++) {
        monthGrid.push(null);
      }
    }
  }

  //on click function that is called whenever a day element is clicked
  function onClickDateRange(e) {
    //gets the date of the element that was clicked
    let date = new Date(datePicker.currentYear, datePicker.currentMonth, e.target.innerText);

    //end date is selected to be overridden, but date is out of bounds (smaller than start date)
    if (dateRange.selectEndDate && dateRange.startDate && date < dateRange.startDate) {
      setDateRange({
        selectStartDate: false,
        selectEndDate: true,
        startDate: date,
        endDate: null,
      });
      return;
    }

    //start date is selected to be overridden, but date is out of bounds (bigger than end date)
    if (dateRange.selectStartDate && dateRange.endDate && date > dateRange.endDate) {
      setDateRange({
        selectStartDate: false,
        selectEndDate: true,
        startDate: date,
        endDate: null,
      });
      return;
    }

    //there is no start date but an end date and date is out of bounds (bigger than end date)
    if (!dateRange.startDate && dateRange.endDate && date > dateRange.endDate) {
      setDateRange({
        selectStartDate: false,
        selectEndDate: true,
        startDate: date,
        endDate: null,
      });
      return;
    }

    //there is no start date but an end date
    if (!dateRange.startDate && dateRange.endDate) {
      setDateRange({
        ...dateRange,
        selectStartDate: false,
        selectEndDate: true,
        startDate: date,
      });
      return;
    }

    //base case if end date is selected
    if (dateRange.selectEndDate) {
      setDateRange({
        ...dateRange,
        endDate: date,
      });
      return;
    }

    //base case if start date is selected
    if (dateRange.selectStartDate) {
      setDateRange({
        ...dateRange,
        selectStartDate: false,
        selectEndDate: true,
        startDate: date,
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  //Handles clicks on the Inputs => sets which dates have to be overwritten
  function onInputStartClick() {
    setDateRange({ ...dateRange, selectStartDate: true, selectEndDate: false });
  }

  function onInputEndClick() {
    setDateRange({ ...dateRange, selectStartDate: false, selectEndDate: true });
  }

  //HELPER FUNCTIONS
  //gets the name of the current month
  function getMonthTitle(month) {
    const months = [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December',
    ];
    return months[month];
  }

  //onclick function that sets the state of the datepicker to preview or next month
  function prevMonth() {
    if (datePicker.currentMonth - 1 < 0) {
      setDatePicker({ currentMonth: 11, currentYear: datePicker.currentYear - 1 });
      return;
    }
    setDatePicker({ ...datePicker, currentMonth: datePicker.currentMonth - 1 });
  }

  function nextMonth() {
    if (datePicker.currentMonth + 1 > 11) {
      setDatePicker({ currentMonth: 0, currentYear: datePicker.currentYear + 1 });
      return;
    }
    setDatePicker({ ...datePicker, currentMonth: datePicker.currentMonth + 1 });
  }

  //onclick function of submmit button that calculates the number of days set in the date range
  function getNumberOfDays() {
    const difference = (dateRange.endDate - dateRange.startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    console.log(difference);
  }

  //onclick function that clears the date range
  function clearDateRange() {
    setDateRange({
      selectStartDate: true,
      selectEndDate: false,
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
    });
  }

  //function that takes a date object as imput and formats it as dd/mm/yyyy
  function getDateFormatted(date) {
    const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

I appretiate any help I can get with this, as I hava no clue how to achieve this effect.
Thanks :)

Comment: First, don't use `document.querySelector`, use `Refs` instead. It will specially cause issues with more than one component in the same window. Second, it will help if you could add css. Live example will be even better. Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-jones-572cy

Answer (score 0):

add a `data-*` attribute to your date element like so

```
<div 
  className='day' 
  key={date} 
  day={date} 
  data-date={UTCdateString} 
  onClick={(e) => onClickDateRange(e)}>
  {element}
</div>
```

assign it with the date utc string of the date.  create a class in your css for the in-range styles you want. inside of your `useEffect` callback, add a condition to check when both start and end dates are selected. inside of the condition, use `querySelectorAll` to select all date elements, go thru those elements in a for-loop or what have you to get the data-date value from each element (element.dataset.date -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)), create a function [stack-over-flow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246092/checking-if-a-date-falls-between-a-range-of-dates) to check if the date falls between the start/end dates, if so, add the class (.in-range or whatever you named it) to that element.

if you feel brave, i would create a dates component for all the business logic then return a mapped array of date components that take in props to render the styles. then get rid of the useEffect querySelector stuff.